# How to create new string column extracting integers from a timestamp in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with a timestamp column, I want a new column which has strings in the format "YYYYMM".

I tried with:

```
df.withColumn('year_month',year(col("timestamp")).cast("string")+month(col("timestamp")).cast("string"))
```

But if my timestamp is 2016-10-12, it returns as 2020 as YYYYMM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date_format`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format
df.withColumn('year_month', date_format('timestamp', 'yyyyMM'))
```

Comment: Great, this works. Any idea why the columns where not cast to string before being concatenated?

Comment: your code would work if you wrapped it inside `concat()` instead of trying to concatenate with `+`.